# access private variable in subclass

Tags: php, class, oop, subclass

I have a class.

```
<?php

class WC_Swatch_Picker {

private $size;
private $attributes;
private $selected_attributes;
private $swatch_type_options;

public function __construct( $product_id, $attributes, $selected_attributes ) {
    $this->swatch_type_options = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_swatch_type_options', true ) );

    if ( !$this->swatch_type_options ) {
        $this->swatch_type_options = array();
    }

    $product_configured_size = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_swatch_size', true );
    if ( !$product_configured_size ) {
        $this->size = 'swatches_image_size';
    } else {
        $this->size = $product_configured_size;
    }

    $this->attributes = $attributes;
    $this->selected_attributes = $selected_attributes;
}

public function picker() {
    ?>

    <table class="variations-table" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $loop = 0;
            foreach ( $this->attributes as $name => $options ) : $loop++;
                $st_name = sanitize_title( $name );
                $hashed_name = md5( $st_name );
                $lookup_name = '';
                if ( isset( $this->swatch_type_options[$hashed_name] ) ) {
                    $lookup_name = $hashed_name;
                } elseif ( isset( $this->swatch_type_options[$st_name] ) ) {
                    $lookup_name = $st_name;
                }
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo $st_name; ?>"><?php echo WC_Swatches_Compatibility::wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        if ( isset( $this->swatch_type_options[$lookup_name] ) ) {
                            $picker_type = $this->swatch_type_options[$lookup_name]['type'];
                            if ( $picker_type == 'default' ) {
                                $this->render_default( $st_name, $options );
                            } else {
                                $this->render_picker( $st_name, $options, $name );
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->render_default( $st_name, $options );
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

I am trying to extend that class so that I can output the `picker()` method that displays `<table>` as a `<div>` instead.

Here is my attempt to extend that class.

```
class SSi_WC_Swatch_Picker extends WC_Swatch_Picker {

public function picker() {
    ?>

    <div class="variations-table">

            <?php

            $loop = 0;
            foreach ( $this->attributes as $name => $options ) : $loop++;
                $st_name = sanitize_title( $name );
                $hashed_name = md5( $st_name );
                $lookup_name = '';
                if ( isset( $this->swatch_type_options[$hashed_name] ) ) {
                    $lookup_name = $hashed_name;
                } elseif ( isset( $this->swatch_type_options[$st_name] ) ) {
                    $lookup_name = $st_name;
                }
                ?>
                <div>
                    <div class="label"><label for="<?php echo $st_name; ?>"><?php echo WC_Swatches_Compatibility::wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></div>
                    <div>
                        <?php
                        if ( isset( $this->swatch_type_options[$lookup_name] ) ) {
                            $picker_type = $this->swatch_type_options[$lookup_name]['type'];
                            if ( $picker_type == 'default' ) {
                                $this->render_default( $st_name, $options );
                            } else {
                                $this->render_picker( $st_name, $options, $name );
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->render_default( $st_name, $options );
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; 

            ?>

    </div>

    <?php
}

}
```

My output on screen shows the `<div>` like I want but I get:
 `Notice: Undefined property: SSi_WC_Swatch_Picker::$attributes` and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I believe that it is because the parent class defines `$attributes` as `private`.

Unfortunately I cannot change the parent class.

So my noob questions is can the `$attributes` be accessed from the subclass somehow? I do not see a __get or __set method in the parent class so I'm guessing there isn't.

The developer is changing the `private` attributes to `protected`. So that will solve my issue of accessing the properties.

Comment: you don't have access to parent's private variables (this is why they are called private), you can save attributes into your variable in constructor though

Comment: Yeah youre going to need to modify the constructor and then keep track of everything in a separate set of member variables. Though at that point you might as well be making an entirely new class unless you need to adhere to a contract with another interface (ie. something requires an instance of WC_Swatch_Picker). Also that `picker` method is ugly. You shouldnt switch in and out of PHP like that in a class. I know this is a WP/WooCommerce thing, but im just throwing that out there so that you **never** do that on your own when you do have a choice :-)

Comment: If it is your own class, you could use `protected` instead of `private`. Then your subclass could access the parent class variables. That kind of violates encapsulation, but it's something you can do.

Comment: @Gohn67 agreed but unfortunately it's not my class, hence not being able to change the parent class. I did put a call out to the developer to see if he would change to `protected` but I have not heard back so trying to find an alternate workaround.

Comment: @Ken maybe you can just copy the class and replace the picker method. No need to subclass then. I don't think it's a big deal in this case.

Comment: @Gohn67 yup, thought of that too, but didn't want to have to maintain it if there are updates to that class in the future. #lazy

Comment: @prodigitalson - in regards to going in and out of PHP, would you recommend echoing the HTML portions or is there another/better way to do it?

Comment: personally I would recommend not creating anything but the simplest html strings within a method otherwise would [recommend using a buffer/include and then returning the string from the buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11707084/215966). Of course there is a performance hit for doing that so sometimes with medium complexity i will use a tokenized string like: `$content = strtr('<div id="%id"><div class="content">%content</div></div>', array('%id'=>'dom-id', '%content' => $someOtherComplexGeneratedContent));`

Comment: Use `getter/setter` for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
// setup a reflector for WC_Swatch_Picker::size property
$ref = new ReflectionProperty("WC_Swatch_Picker", "size");
$ref->setAccessible(true);

// read the private "size" property
$size = $ref->getValue($this);

// update the private "size" property
$ref->setValue($this, $size);
```

Note: this is somewhat inefficient, so if you're going to do this a lot, you should keep a copy of the ReflectionProperty instance to be reused as needed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will have to look into this more as its completely out of my wheelhouse. I assume I would create 2 reflections, based on the 4 private properties? Would your suggestion go inside my extended class but before the `picker()` method?

Comment: I think you'd probably set up 4 reflections, one for each property.  And you'd probably do that in the extended class's constructor I think; that way you don't keep recreating the reflection objects.  I'd also just caution that this approach is ugly and should only be used if you can't change the base class from private to protected.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to override the constructor in your child class and set your own property `$attributes`:

```
class SSi_WC_Swatch_Picker extends WC_Swatch_Picker {

    private $attributes;

    public function __construct( $product_id, $attributes, $selected_attributes ) {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;

        // Call the parent constructor.
        parent::__construct( $product_id, $attributes, $selected_attributes );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This would probably cause problems because there would be two $attributes properties, one private in the base class, and one private in the subclass.  Different methods would get different data.  You may be able to resolve that by using pass byref (&$attributes), but I'm not sure.

Comment: You're right but there is no clean way to do that. Your solution is nice but brakes the accessibility of the property. Without modifying the parent class I cannot see a good way to do this.